# jdbcTemplate.update for auto incremented and unique ID field

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table that has 4 fields; `ID`, `NAME`, `AGE`, `SALARY`. `ID` is unique and auto-increment.

Below is the code to insert a row in the table, using Spring's `JDBCTemplate`. Please suggest, how can I auto increment `ID` field.

```
String sql = "insert into employee values (?,?,?,?)"
jdbcTemplate.update( sql, ID, bean.getName(), bean.getAge(), bean.getSalary())
```

Comment: how does your domain look like??

Comment: Share your Employee class code

Comment: `employee` is a table not a class.

Answer (score 1):

I see, you tag your question `Oracle`, use Oracle `sequence` then.

```
String sql = "insert into Employee values (id_seq.nextval, ?, ?, ?)";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, bean.getName(), bean.getAge(), bean.getSalary());
```

Ref: [How to create Sequence in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code to your domain:
Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;

final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into my_test (name) values(?)";
                final String name = "Rob";
                KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
                jdbcTemplate.update(
                        new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                                PreparedStatement ps =
                                        connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"id"});
                                ps.setString(1, name);
                                return ps;
                            }
                        },
                        keyHolder);
```

Comment: It says JDBCTemplate. She is not using JPA or any other ORM, it seems.